# removing last patching kernel

Tags: git, patch

I build openwrt firmware and I just used a pr (patch kernel update) with `patch -p1 < filename.patch` and I want to remove to reapply a new one, what would be the best?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revert the patch:

```
patch -R -p1 < filename.patch
```